# Magento 1.9 server to localhost many errors in windows 10

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost

I have an magento 1.9.3.7 installation on my server. I have to change something on codes. SSL is activated on server. I using ampps on my localhost. Error is

```
    Warning: file_get_contents(\app\etc\modules\Mstoreapp_App.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in \lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 496

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'file_get_conten...', 'C:\\Program File...', 496, Array)
#1 \lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php(496): file_get_contents('C:\\Program File...')
#2 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(791): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile('C:\\Program File...')
#3 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#4 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#5 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 \app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 \index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should be without access to read the files, set the folder permissions by following the documentation: [After You Install Magento: Recommended File System Ownership and Privileges](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But i using windows 10 and don't know anything about web app permission. So how i do that?

Comment: you need to access the server or request the hosting service to perform the fix.